# Implementing KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol for URL types

Tags: swift, codable, decoder, decodable, encodable

I'm working on a project to create a custom `Decoder` to deal with non JSON data.

Data to decode can be `URL`s or `String`s. For example:

```
struct MyData: Decodable {
    let server: URL
    let version: String
}
```

In order to deal with such a type of decoding, I've implemented a class, called `KeyedContainer`, that implements the `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol`.

For a `String` is quite simple since I can use the following method:

```
func decode(_ type: String.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> String { }
```

For an `URL`, instead, I need to rely on the following:

```
func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> T where T: Decodable { }
```

Within it, I do something like the following:

```
func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
    try checkCanDecodeValue(forKey: key)

    guard let value = configuration[key.stringValue] else {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "TODO")
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: value) else {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "TODO")
        throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(type, context)
    }

    return url as! T
}
```

where `configuration` is a struct that is passed along to `KeyedContainer` directly from the custom decoder.

Is this the right approach? What I'm not sure about is the `as! T` cast in order to make the compiler happy.

Comment: What is wrong with the `Decodable`?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Nothing wrong. I would like just to know if you can suggest a different approach for `URL`.

Comment: I mean why you don't want to use it? Conform to decodable and implement custom decode function.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. I need to maintain the custom decoder @MojtabaHosseini

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have to hard cast to T if you do:

```swift
    guard let url = URL(string: value) as? T else {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "TODO")
        throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(type, context)
    }
```